# Why is my NSDecimalNumber's boolValue NO on iOS 7, but YES on iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, boolean, nsdecimalnumber

I have a `NSDecimalNumber` which represents 0.5, declared and debugged as below:

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNumber = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:0.5];
NSLog(@"Bool value: %@", myNumber.boolValue ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

On iOS 7.1.1, I get this:

```
2016-01-26 11:11:19.878 MyApp[467:60b] Bool value: NO
```

On iOS 8.4.1, I get this:

```
2016-01-26 11:15:42.128 MyApp[467:60b] Bool value: YES
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, the -[NSDecimalNumber boolValue] method would return `NO` iff the integer part of the number was equal to `0`, and `YES` otherwise. In iOS 8, this was changed to be consistent with other `NSNumber`s, and look at the whole number, so only values exactly equal to `0` would return `NO`.

You can see this with the LLDB console:

### iOS 7

[image: p (BOOL)[[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:0.5] boolValue] prints (BOOL) $3 = NO]

### iOS 8

[image: p (BOOL)[[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:0.5] boolValue] prints (BOOL) $4 = YES]

---

## Workaround

An easy workaround is to make this more semantic. **What are you trying to do?** Chances are, you just want to know if the value inside the `NSDecimalNumber` is non-zero. In that case, use this instead:

```
NSLog(@"Is decimal number non-zero? %@", [myNumber compare:@0] != NSOrderedSame ? @"YES", @"NO");
```

Or if you want to check if it's been set at all:

```
NSLog(@"Is decimal number set? %@", myNumber ? @"YES", @"NO");
```